# MySQL vs php files

Tags: mysql, database

Firstly, this isn't a question about whether MySQL is faster than text files (I already know it is); but rather whether MySQL is also faster than storing db entries as php files containing arrays that wouldn't need to be parsed by code, merely read in as a php array. I would assume this would be faster than MySQL, wouldn't it?

I'm asking because many hosting services either place strict limits on MySQL database storage, or charge a relatively large amount of money (e.g. Rackspace charges about seven times more for a GB of MySQL storage than a GB of regular storage, making the latter far more cost-effective).

Comment: Incorrect: "arrays that wouldn't need to be parsed by code." ... the PHP interpreter needs to parse them.

Comment: But what about transaction management and concurrency? How would you handle that?

Comment: I don't think your'e getting the point of a DB.

Comment: Let me see if I understand correctly: You want an opinion of (in terms of speed) what is better: to store files as BLOBs in your MySQL database, or to store the files in a defined path in your server and store the path to the file in your MySQL database. Am I right?

Comment: Svidgen - yes, I know; but it's far faster for the PHP interpreter to parse them than for my PHP code to do it. Loading in a PHP array from a file should be faster than fetching it from MySQL and then putting it in an array, should it not?

Comment: Barranka : well, I wouldn't need to store the file path in a MySQL db since the file path and name would be based on the user ID. I.e., each user would have a separate file in the form of a php file containing an array.

Comment: Vincent Ramdhanie  - Each user file would generally only be modified by the user himself, hence there generally wouldn't be concurrency problems.